# JES f==None not working

Tags: jes

I'm using JES version 5.010. I'm trying to do this assignment for school:

> For the first part of the assignment, you are going to write a
>   function that will select, using pickAFile(), a picture file to be
>   opened. If cancel is pressed in the pickAFile() dialogue box, then you
>   must ask the user if it was a mistake. If it was a mistake, open the
>   pickAFile() dialogue again, and repeat until it is either not a
>   mistake, or a picture file was selected. If a picture file is
>   selected, return the 'made' picture, otherwise (i.e. cancel was pushed
>   and the user indicated that it was NOT a mistake) return an error
>   message. NOTE: the JES function requestString (see JES
>   Functions-->Input/Output) should be used when asking the user if the
>   pressing of 'cancel' was a mistake.

For some reason my if statement, if f==None, isn't working properly and I have no clue why. My code is below

```
def assign3PartA():
  noFile = True
  while noFile:
    f = pickAFile()
    if f==None: #This is what isn't working
       noFile=mistake()
       noFile = False
       print "Invalid option, you must select a picture to continue!" 
    else: #Working fine
      pic = makePicture(f)
      show(pic)
      break
  def mistake():
    ask = requestString("Did you press cancel by mistake? Enter yes or no. ")
    if ask == "yes" or ask == "Yes":
      return True
    elif ask == "No" or ask == "no":
      return False
    else:
      print "Try again. Please enter either yes or no."
      mistake()
```

I have also tried if f is None as well and that didn't work.
Any help you can give is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? What outcome are you expecting and what are you getting instead?

Comment: When I exist out of the file selector instead of picking a file I want it to go through the if loop but for some reason it doesn't. Instead it tries to go through the else statement and I get an error message: Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error sigh. I get needed to put None in quotation marks. 
if j == "None":